# Dúvida específica usando ng-repeat no angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

Estou usando AngularJS em um projeto onde preciso exibir uma lista de fotos de produtos cadastrados no sistema e meu `html` está assim:

```
// Titulo para a área de produtos
<div class="header-products">
  <h3>Produtos</h3>
</div>

// Ng-repeat para listar os produtos, somente serão exibidos produtos com foto
<div class="photo" ng-repeat="product in products | limitTo: 3" ng-if="product.imageUrl">
  <img ng-src="{{ product.imageUrl }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" 
      title="{{ product.name }}" ng-if="product.imageUrl" />
</div>
```

porém a `div` ***header-products*** só deve ser exibida se pelo menos um produtos da minha lista tiver foto, se não tiver nenhuma foto não exibo este `header`. Na lista sempre terá o nome do produtos mas pode s er que nao tenha a foto:

```
[
 {produto: 'lapis', imageUrl: 'url-da-imagem'},
 {produto: 'caneta', imageUrl: 'url-da-imagem'},
 {produto: 'borracha', imageUrl: ''}
]
```

Como posso fazer isso se meu `header` esta fora do `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Olá Felipe, você já tentou utilizar o ng-if? Algo como: <div ng-if="checked"></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque a diretiva [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) perguntando se a lista de `products` ***é maior do que zero***, *exemplo*:

```
<div ng-show="products.length > 0" class="header-products">
  <h3>Produtos</h3>
</div>
```

Abaixo um exemplo funcional, onde a `div` com o titulo **Produtos** vai aparecer, enquanto que a `div` com o titulo **Alimentos** não, porque, `products` tem elementos para apresentar e `aliments` não.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'name1'
    },
    {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'name2'
    },
  ];
  $scope.aliments = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-show="products.length > 0" class="header-products">
    <h3>Produtos</h3>
  </div>


  <div ng-show="aliments.length > 0" class="header-products">
    <h3>Alimentos</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Com a nova edição da pergunta tinha um item que não foi mencionado que só aparece a `header` se alguns dos itens de `products` contiver **foto**, então faça uma função que vai percorrer essa lista e buscar o primeiro item com imagem, **exemplo**:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{
      produto: 'lapis',
      imageUrl: ''
    },
    {
      produto: 'caneta',
      imageUrl: ''
    },
    {
      produto: 'borracha',
      imageUrl: 'a'
    }
  ]
  $scope.showItem = function() {
    var sts = false;
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.products[i].imageUrl !== '') {
        sts = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return sts;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-show="showItem()" class="header-products">
    <h3>Produtos</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

<sub>***Referencia***</sub>

- [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)
- [AngularJS - Entendendo as diretivas **ng-show** e **ng-hide**](https://blog.mxcursos.com/angularjs-entendendo-as-diretivas-ng-show-e-ng-hide/)

Comment: Tem um detalhe que acabei não explicando. Minha lista é assim:
[
{produto: 'lapis', imageUrl: 'url-da-imagem'},
{produto: 'caneta', imageUrl: 'url-da-imagem'},
{produto: 'borracha', imageUrl: 'url-da-imagem'}
]

Porém pode ser que só um ou dois produtos tenham foto. Para exibir o titulo preciso verificar se pelo menos um dos  itens tem foto senão não exibo nada.

Comment: @FelipeCoelho mas, isso não muda nada na resposta veja, que até coloque dois exemplos, mas, diga ai o que aconteceu? se não deu certo, é melhor você editar a sua pergunta e colocar tudo que precisa.!

Comment: Editei a perguntando. Valeu

Comment: @FelipeCoelho editado a resposta